# Multiplication of a Range

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Say I have a number, "a".  0 < a < 5.
Let's say I have another number, "b".  0 < b < 10

Is ab < 50?

If you were to write this as a * b < 5 * b, you would find that the upper bound is < than 50, since b is strictly less than 10. 5 * <10 = < 50

If the upper bound is less than 50, doesn't a have to be less than a number that's less than 50, and not 50 itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "less than less than"?

Comment: Basically, in the example, shouldn't ab < 49.999999999999... (the largest number preceding 50)

Comment: There is no largest number less than $50$, the number you wrote down is equal to $50$. What is true is that if $ab < 50$, then $ab < k$ for some (in fact infinitely many) $k < 50$.

Comment: Yes, I know that 0.9999999999999999999... = 1.
But if there is no largest number < 50, then what about 49.5? 49.9?  Since b is not exactly 10 (it has to be less), shouldn't the actual upper bound is less than 50?  And therefore it would not be 50, but some number < 50?

Comment: As MJD put in his answer, the upper bound can't be any smaller than $50$ because given a potential upper bound $k$ with $k < 50$, you can find $a$ and $b$ with $0 < a < 5$ and $0 < b < 10$ such that $ab \geq k$.

Comment: But how could k = 50 if b < 10?  5 * 10 = 50, but 10 is not less than 10.

Comment: Writing $ab < 50$ does not mean that there are values $a$ and $b$ such that $ab = 50$ it means that for *any* choice of $a$ and $b$, $ab$ will be less than $50$.

Comment: Well, what I meant was that since a < 5, then ab < 5b.  But since b < 10, then 5b < 50.  And since 5b (the upper bound) is less than 50, then ab < a bit less than 50.

Comment: Yes, if 0<a<5 and 0<b<10, ab<50.  a is less than 50, and not 50 itself, yes.

Comment: @Tim: If you know what $b$ is, then $5b$ is a helpful upper bound (i.e. a number you can write down). The problem is that as you want to find an upper bound for $ab$ for any possible choices of $a$ and $b$, so even though $5b < 50$, because $5b$ can be arbitrarily close to $50$, we can't write down a number which is a better upper bound for $ab$ than $50$ without knowing what $b$ is (or similarly, what $a$ is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use only one "less than" sign.

Consider this as an analogy: Just as we would **not** say: $a = 5$, $b = 5$, so therefore $a + b$ "equals equals" $10$, but rather, we'd conclude that $a + b = 10$. In your case, we would not say $ab$ "is less than less than" $50$, but rather, $ab < 50$.

For any two real numbers, $x, y$, one and only one of the following is true:

- $x < y\quad$ OR (x less than y)
- $x = y\quad$ OR (x equals y)
- $x > y\quad$ (x is greater than y)

---

**EDIT following question edit:**

To answer the question in the comment below: There is no *largest number preceding 50*: For every $k < 50$, there is a $j$ such that $k < j < 50$, and there is an $m$ such that $k < j < m < 50...$ and on and on and on...for every *proposed* "largest number $n$ preceding 50", there is a *larger number* than $n$ preceding 50.

In this case, for example, take any possible choice of $ab < 50$. Then there exists $x =  \large \frac {50 + ab}{2}$ $> ab$ but nonetheless, $x < 50$. If we then let $ab = x$, there exists $y = \large\frac {50 + x}{2}$ $> x,$ with $y< 50$...and so on.

The least upper bound for $ab$, in this case, is ***not in*** the set of possible values for $ab$.  Think of it like this:  $$ 0 < a < 5,\;\;0 < b < 10, \;\; \implies \;\; ab \in (0, 50),$$ where $(0, 50)$ is the **open interval** of reals greater than $0$ but less than $50$ (the interval of all real numbers from $0$ to $50$, ***excluding*** $0$ and $50$:

$$ab \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 < x < 50\}$$

Comment: By "less than less than", I meant, "shouldn't a < the largest number preceding 50, instead of 50 itself?"

Comment: But if 10b < 50, and ab < 10b, then isn't "50" an inexact upper bound? Isn't the actual upper bound less than 50?

Comment: $50$ is the least upper bound in this case, even given the fact that $ab < 50$. That is not to say $ab = 50$.

Comment: but wouldn't 50 not satisfy the inequality x < 50?

Comment: See the edited answer (end of answer).

Comment: So basically the reason why the upper bound is 50 is because there is no largest number less than 50?

Comment: Tim: Yes, you're correct. $50$ is an upper bound because there is no *largest* (real) number less than 50. But $50$ is more than an upper bound of $ab$: it is the *least upper bound* of $ab$.

Comment: Nicely done Amy.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The product $ab$ is less than 50, but it's not "less than less than 50", because it can be as close to 50 as you want to make it: for any number $x$ at all, if $x<50$, then there is some $a$ and $b$ with $x < ab < 50$.

For example, say $x = 50 - \frac1{1,000}$.  But then with $a = 5 - \frac1{1,000,000}$ and $b = 10-\frac1{1,000,000}$, you get $x < ab < 50$: $x = 49.999$, but $ab = 49.999985000001$, which is even closer to 50 than $x$ is.  And you can do this for any $x$ at all, no matter how close to 50 it is.

There is no "largest number preceding 50". For any $x < 50$, the number $25 + \frac x2$ is bigger than $x$ and still smaller than 50.

Comment: But if 10b < 50, then isn't the upper bound of ab less than 50, and not 50 itself?

Comment: No; suppose you have some number $x$ which you think might be an upper bound for $ab$, but with $x<50$.  It's always possible to find $a$ and $b$ so that $ab$ will be closer to 50 than $x$ is, with $x < ab < 50$, which shows that $x$ isn't in fact an upper bound for $ab$.

Answer (score 1):

The basic definition of "<" for real numbers
is that $u < v$ means that
there is a positive real number $w$ such that
$u + w = v$.

If $0 < a < 5$, there is a positive number $p < 5$
such that $a+p = 5$.
Similarly,
if $0 < b < 10$,
there is a positive number $q < 10$
such that
$b+q = 10$.

So
$a b = (5-p)(10-q)
= 50 - 10p -5q + pq
$.
Since $p < 5$
and $q < 10$,
both $10p$ and $5q$
are greater than $pq$,
so $10p+5q-pq > 0$,
so $ab < 50$.

This clearly generalizes.